# Does Megumin just need more MP?

Tags: konosuba

Megumin's explosion spell drains her to the point where she cannot move, and she can only use it once a day, but could she move if she had more MP (or whatever equivalent *KonoSuba* uses) for casting? It could be that the spell cost is defined such that it drains all MP, but there's evidence there's at least a minimum MP requirement, because she was unable to cast it after Kazuma drained some of her MP in one episode, though she wasn't at zero MP. But we see in some episodes Megumin can cast the spell twice if Kazuma uses his drain spell to give her more MP. So, is raising your MP a thing in *KonoSuba* (I'd think it would be, since it has an explicit leveling and stats system), and could Megumin potentially move after casting her explosion, and maybe even cast it twice in one day if she doubled or tripled her MP?

**Do the light novels or manga have any information that would answer this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Crimson Demon Clan is a clan naturally gifted with magic and intelligence so they have high mana reserves, Megumin included. But the thing here is that Explosion Magic drains so much mana that not even the highly skilled Arch Wizards in the Crimson Village can cast it twice without resting. If we're talking about Megumin here, She only chooses to spend all her points into Explosion Magic and nothing else.

That being said, there is a way to cast more Explosion Magic continuously which is to find a Mana source. Kazuma did this in the anime via transferring mana from Aqua to Megumin, letting her cast another one in the process.

Or use an item that can give you mana when you use it. One of the better known one is the Manatite which can store mana and is capable of even powering up magic. Megumin got a whole load of them in the last volume (vol 17) which had higher purity than normal ones (higher purity = higher mana and magic amplification) and she used them to cast off her Explosion Magic like a madman until they got depleted.

So why not just use them off then? Turns out the things are very expensive to the point that the highest purity of them can buy out a whole house and their usage is also one-time so Adventurers tend to avoid them.

So, even if she does increase her MP, Chances are she still can't cast it twice, but she can use some alternatives to help her use it twice or even thousands of times.

Answer (score 4):

Megumin has spent all of her XP into improving "Explosion", at the expense of every other possible skill or spell - this is mentioned in the *Legend of Crimson* film, and also I believe in the show itself.

What this implies is that she always levels "Explosion" to the point where she can create the largest explosion possible, which probably requires that she spend all her MP to do so. If she does have an opportunity to deliberately increase her MP, it seems likely that she would also increase "Explosion" to match, and so would stay at the once-per-day limit.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that her having more MP could allow her to cast it more than once without kazuma having to use his drain spell to give her more MP. So in that regard, you are correct. The main thing for her would be to control her spells more and to learn how to exercise that same amount of power, but with more control and learn how to do it without expending so much MP. It would make more sense if she could double or triple her MP. And even if she doubled it that would solve the problem, and if she tripled it there would be virtually no issues with her being able to move after casting the spell. So to answer your question, would she need to double or triple her MP? Yes she would. But control, and proper MP use play a major factor as well.